# Redux compare each index of array

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I was trying to add an state which suppose to have a array of indexes and each of these index must compare with state index and delete of store state, for example I have a product's state:

```
state.products = [
    {productName: "patric", withTax: "0.57", noTax: "2.30", tax: 25, quantity: 2}
    {productName: "parafuso", withTax: "55.50", noTax: "222.00", tax: 25, quantity: 2} //remove this
    {productName: "mamao", withTax: "0.57", noTax: "2.30", tax: 25, quantity: 5} // remove this
]

action.index = [
    {productName: "parafuso", withTax: "55.50", noTax: "222.00", tax: 25, quantity: 2} //remove this
    {productName: "mamao", withTax: "0.57", noTax: "2.30", tax: 25, quantity: 5} // remove this
]

    //this is not removing the selecteds items
    const products = state.products.filter((product, i) => {

        for(let i=0; i < action.index.length; i++){
            if(product.name !== action.index[i].name) return true
        }

        return false
    }) 
    return {
        ...state,
        products
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `.filter()` function as it returns an immutable array of the array without the value you want to delete.
I'm assuming that your asking about removing an element from state inside your reducer, your question kind of seems all over the place...

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter

```
state.products [
  {name: pudim},
  {name: car}, //want to remove this
  {name: cloud} //want to remove this
]

//Reducer code...

case ProductActionType.SELECT_PRODUCT: { 
  const products = state.products.filter((product, index) => { 
    for(let i=0; i < action.productFromAction.length; i++){
        if(product.name === action.productFromAction[i].name) return false
    }
    return true
  }) 
  return { ...state, products } 
}
```

Comment: Actually the 'action.productFromAction.name' is also an array which have the objects rows to delete, but if I enter like this, I cannot read throught the array to check each name of object.

`
 case ProductActionType.SELECT_PRODUCT: {
  const indexedProduct = action.index.map(index => {
   return state.products[index]
  })
  const products = state.products.filter((product, i) => {
   return product.name !== indexedProduct[i].name
  })
  console.log(products)

  return {
   ...state
  }
 }
`

Just to clarify this, i want to delete the 2 index in a row, is that possible?

Comment: You can't filter it simply by index, there has to be some kind of unique identifier for each element in your data store that maps to your array of data.  If you just try to check by index, it won't always give you the correct value.  So in this instance, I'm going to assume your name is a unique identifier.  If it is, try this:

Comment: I updated my answer to include filtering out an array of elemnts.  Let me know if that works for you.

Comment: No this isn't working as expected, it is removing all indexes.

Comment: May you please console.log what your action is passing in for me?

Comment: `
outside the filter func: [{"productName":"parafuso","withTax":"55.50","noTax":"222.00","tax":25,"quantity":2},{"productName":"mamao","withTax":"0.57","noTax":"2.30","tax":25,"quantity":5}]
`

`
calling the func filter: [{"productName":"patric","withTax":"0.57","noTax":"2.30","tax":25,"quantity":2},{"productName":"parafuso","withTax":"55.50","noTax":"222.00","tax":25,"quantity":2},{"productName":"mamao","withTax":"0.57","noTax":"2.30","tax":25,"quantity":5}]
 `

Comment: inside the loop I got undefined when trying to read the action.index

Comment: It is working almost, its only deleting only one per click and not all selected in a dispatch action.

Comment: Sounds like an issue with the indexing maybe?  I revised a bit because I realized I was duplicating the `i` variable (oops!).  I would console.log the values inside the loop.  In a filter function, you want the elements that are being removed to return false.  Every other element should return true.  I hope this helps!

Comment: Wow now It works, I needed also to block undefined return statement.

Answer (score 1):

I would take a similar but optimised approach.

First of all I would just extract the names of the products you want to remove since it makes no sense to run a for look for every item of the products you have in the state.

Second, having an `indexOf` instead of a `for` loop with equality operator `===` performs faster since the browser can optimise the execution.

Finally, try to improve readability.

```
// Given that this is your state
state.products [
  {productName: "patric", withTax: "0.57", noTax: "2.30", tax: 25, quantity: 2}
  {productName: "parafuso", withTax: "55.50", noTax: "222.00", tax: 25, quantity: 2} //remove this
  {productName: "mamao", withTax: "0.57", noTax: "2.30", tax: 25, quantity: 5} // remove this
]

// Given that this is the action you dispatch
action = {
  type: 'FILTER_PRODUCTS'
  index: [
    {productName: "parafuso", withTax: "55.50", noTax: "222.00", tax: 25, quantity: 2} //remove this
    {productName: "mamao", withTax: "0.57", noTax: "2.30", tax: 25, quantity: 5} // remove this
  ]
}

//Reducer code...
case 'FILTER_PRODUCTS': {

  // extract the names just once
  const namesToRemove = action.index.map( product => product.name )

  // filter the products
  const products = state.products.filter( product => namesToRemove.indexOf( product.name ) === -1 )

  return { ...state, products } 
}
```

### EDIT

You can also replace the `Array.indexOf` with the newer `Array.includes`.

```
const products = state.products.filter( product => namesToRemove.indexOf( product.name ) === -1 )
```

becomes

```
const products = state.products.filter( product => ! namesToRemove.includes( product.name ) )
```

Comment: I suggested to replace indexOf with includes since it is more clear

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep only the product with the index in the state, this can be done with the filter function.

like this

```js
let state = {
  products: [{
      name: 'pudim'
    },
    {
      name: 'car'
    },
    {
      name: 'cloud'
    }
  ],
  index: [1,2] 
}

const withoutRemoved = state.products.filter((product, i) => state.index.indexOf(i) === -1 )

console.log( {
  ...state,
  products: withoutRemoved
})
```

`map`always returns an array with the same spaces even if they are `` `undefined`

Comment: Yeah I agree with you, but, I don't want to do this, what I want to is to delete not one, but multiple indexes at same time, for example 2 rows of a table is equals to 2 indexes of my Array, and I want to delete those 2 rows at the same time.

Comment: instead of using simple index use an array and filter the products which indexes ain't in the array

Comment: i just updated the example to work with an array of indexes to delete

Comment: I will use your logic.